# This song ... many memories for me

Tags: word-request

Which word should I use when I mention a song which reminds me of some memories.

> Someone : Do you listen to these old songs?
>
> Me : Yeah these songs  convey a  lot of memories for me.

Does it sound natural?

Comment: _Yeah these songs hold a lot of memories for me._

Comment: Or even further -  Yeah, these songs get me a wave of *nostalgia*

Answer (score 6):

The verb *convey* is not really common in combination with *memories*. The verb you are probably looking for is ***evoke***:

> to make someone ​remember something or ​feel an ​emotion ([source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/evoke))

Songs do not really *convey* a memory. Have a look at the definition for *convey*:

> to ​express a ​thought, ​feeling, or ​idea so that it is ​understood by other ​people ([source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/convey))

Sentences can convey meaning, for example. Songs, however, make you think of things that happened in the past. They cause you to think of these *memories*, which is exactly what *evoke* means (*to **make** someone **remember***...).

So, considering your sentence it would be more idiomatic to say:

> Yeah these songs **evoke** a lot of memories.

You can leave out the *for me* (though you do not have to), as it will be understood that you are talking about your own memories.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to *evoke* (which is a good choice), you can also use ***[bring back](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bring-back)***.
(*bring back* has one advantage: it's a phrasal verb, so it'd sound more idiomatic in spoken English.)

> *Yeah, these songs **bring back** a lot of (good old) memories (for me).*